# Maximizing $\sin x \cos x + \cos x$ geometrically

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Using basic calculus, it's easy to see that we have a maximum at $ x = \pi/6$, but is there a way to prove this geometrically? I can get the $\cos x \sin x$ to appear but I'm stuck here; how should I proceed with maximizing the sum of length of the base + hypotenuse ($\cos x \sin x + \cos x$)? Any hints would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: One can use the fact that maximum perimeter of inscribed triangle is obtained for equilateral triangle

Answer (score 7):

Factorize the given expression to get $(\cos x)[\sin x + 1]$

The given expression is just the area of the rectangle as shown in the following figure.

It is not difficult to see that the three medium sized triangles are congruent.

By midpoint theorem, the line $\cos x \times \sin x$ is half the line BC, which is $\cos x$.

This means $\dfrac {\sin x \cos x}{cos x} = 0.5$

[image]
According to the following figure, x has to be $\dfrac {\pi}{6}$.